# Why exact propagators as external lines in Feynman diagrams are assigned a factor of $1$ in perturbation theory in all orders?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, feynman-diagrams, perturbation-theory, propagator

I'm reading Srednicki's QFT and I've met a problem in a footnote of section 19. In calculating the Feynman diagrams to all perturbative orders, we only calculate tree-level diagrams but use exact vertex and propagators, the author says that we can assign factor 1 for each external lines because in the LSZ formula, each Klein–Gordon wave operator becomes (in momentum space) a factor of $ k_i^2 + m^2 $($k_i$ is the  momentum of the particle) that multiplies each external propagator, leaving behind **only** the residue of the pole in that propagator at $k_i^2 = −m^2$ and this residue is one (which can be seen from the Lehmann-Kallen form of the propagator).

My question is , why a single factor $k^2+m^2$ have the ability to kill all other terms in $\Delta(k^2)$ and **only** leave the residue of the pole? How is the residue theorem applied here? I understand why the residue is one, but how can we cancel other terms in $\Delta(k^2)$ in addition to $\frac{1}{k^2+m^2}$ in its Laurent expansion at $k^2=-m^2$? (I think the relevant part of the integration is of the form $\int e^{ik_ix}dx^4\int dk^4 \Delta(k^2)(k^2+m^2)e^{ik(x-y)}$ where $\Delta(k^2)$ is the **exact** propagator)

Answer (score 1):

Good question. The full propagator is $\frac{1}{k^2+m^2 -i \epsilon- \Pi(k^2)}$, external lines that are on-shell have the conditions: $\Pi(-m^2) = 0$, and $\Pi'(-m^2) = 0$, so you get residue one for on-shell external lines if you plug in these conditions, and it basically  looks like: $\frac{1}{k^2+m^2}$ (If you are looking for more details, you could consult Kallen-Lehmann representation, chapter 13, and chapter 14). This factor from the propagator can always be cancelled from the LSZ formula. Hope it helps. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think it doesn't solve my question. Although the exact propagator basically looks like $\frac{1}{k^2+m^2}$, it has other terms in its Laurent expansion. My question is: how can we cancel other terms in addition to $\frac{1}{k^2+m^2}$ by simply using a factor $k^2+m^2$?

Comment: This is the only term, and there is a $k^2+m^2$ coming from the LSZ in the numerator, and they cancel exactly. Could you write it out, perhaps, like show what you mean and what doesn't cancel for clarity? Maybe that will help clarify the doubt.

Comment: exact propagator in the Kallen-Lehmann form is $
\tilde{\boldsymbol{\Delta}}\left(k^{2}\right)=\frac{1}{k^{2}+m^{2}-i \epsilon}+\int_{4 m^{2}}^{\infty} d s \rho(s) \frac{1}{k^{2}+s-i \epsilon}
$, it has an additional term besides$ \frac{1}{k^{2}+m^{2}}$,althouth it does't contribute to the residue.

Comment: Yes, that term (second) on-shell ($k^2 = -m^2$) doesn't contribute; the first term is the contribution of introducing one-particle states in the propagator definition, while the second term is for left-over multi-particle states. In a more simple terms: now, if you multiply $k^2+m^2$ from LSZ see that in the first term they cancel out, in second term there is nothing to cancel out $k^2+m^2$, which is basically : $-m^2+m^2 = 0$. If you are wondering why there is nothing to cancel it in second term: the limit of integral starts from $4m^2$. So, you are effectively multiplying that term by 0.

Comment: I think I get it, thanks.